# How do I hide "hot network questions" on Stack Exchange with Firefox?

Tags: support, hot-questions, sidebar

I like using Stack Exchange websites. I often find myself clicking on hot network questions and that time is frequently not spend productively.

Is there a way when I use Firefox to hide that element from the page?